# Pointer Arithmetic in C using Array Variables

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am in the process of learning C, and have begun exploring the world of pointers and pointer arithmetic. For example,  in the following code snippet:

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

`nums` is an Array variable and acts like a pointer that points to the first memory location of the array. I wrote the following sample code and am trying to understand why I am getting the results that I am getting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{
  int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};

  if(nums == &nums)
    puts("nums == &nums");
  else
    puts("nums != &nums");

  if((nums + 1) == (&nums + 1))
    puts("(nums + 1) == (&nums + 1)");
  else
    puts("(nums + 1) != (&nums + 1)");    

  printf("nums: %i\n", nums);
  printf("&nums: %i\n", &nums);
  printf("nums + 1: %i\n", nums + 1);
  printf("&nums + 1: %i\n", &nums + 1);

  return 0;    
}
```

I am getting that `nums == &nums` is true as expected; however, when I apply pointer arithmetic and add `1` to `nums` this result does not equal `&nums + 1`. In other words `(nums + 1) != (&nums + 1)` even though `nums == &nums`.

This is the output of the program that I get:

```
nums == &nums
(nums + 1) != (&nums + 1)
nums: 2345600
&nums: 2345600
nums + 1: 2345604
&nums + 1: 2345612
```

It appears that `nums` and `nums + 1` are off set by 4 bytes; however, `&nums` and `&nums + 1` are offset by 12. Why is it that this offset is by 12 bytes and not by 4?

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider using `%p` to printf pointer values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [So you think you know pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232303/so-you-think-you-know-pointers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion is related to how in C, arrays implicitly decay into pointers in certain contexts.

The easier one to explain, `nums + 1` effectively means `&nums[0] + 1`. `nums[0]` is type `int`, which is 4 bytes per element. Thus `&nums[0] + 1` is 4 bytes after `&nums`.

As for `&nums + 1`, `&nums` is of type `int(*)[3]`, which is 12 bytes per element. Thus `&nums + 1` is 12 bytes after `&nums`.

Comment: Interesting, this would mean that if I wanted to get the next memory location directly after the array I could use "&nums + 1". Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However you cannot actually use that memory location, because it would invoke *undefined behavior*. Nor are you allowed to compute any memory locations past the end, either.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions, `(int*) nums` and `&nums` have pointer types, but the types pointed to are different. You only can test them for equality in C, not C++.

The type of `nums` is `int[3]`, that is, 'array of 3 objects of type `int`' and the type of `(int*) nums` is `int*`, that is, 'a pointer to `int`' . Adding 1 to `(int*) nums` means obtaining a pointer to an object of type `int` that follows `nums[0]`. In terms of addresses that means adding `1 * sizeof (int)`.

The type of `&nums` is `int(*)[3]`, that is, 'pointer to an array of 3 objects of type `int`'. Adding 1 to `&nums` means obtaining a pointer to an object of type `int[3]` that follows `nums`. In terms of addresses that means adding `1 * sizeof (int[3])`, that is, `3 * sizeof (int)`.